# Executing non empty promise results while disregarding empty results

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I have this code that executes a function to promise 4 public methods, the public methods have code to return nothing if they don't meet a certain criteria. If one of the results is empty (undefined), I want it to disregard that result BUT still keep the and execute the other results. Anyone have an idea on how to do this or a workaround for it?

```
async sendFreeGames(channels) {
        Promise.all([this.createEpicFreeGamesEmbeds(), this.createSteamFreeGamesEmbeds(), this.createEpicFreeButtons(), this.createSteamFreeButtons()]).then(
            (results) => {
                const games = [...results[0], ...results[1]];
                const buttons = [...results[2], ...results[3]];

                if (games.length === 0) return;

                for (const channel of channels) {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    const discordAxios = axios.create({
                        baseURL: 'https://discord.com/api/v10',
                        headers: { Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN}` },
                    });
                    discordAxios.post(`/channels/${channel.data.id}/messages`, { embeds: games, components: [{ type: 1, components: buttons }] });
                }
            },
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Filter out the empty results: `results = results.filter(r => r !== undefined)`

Comment: `results = results.filter(r => r != undefined)`

Comment: by "nothing", what do you mean? An empty array `[]`? `undefined`? `null`? I'm not sure I understand because they will all execute no matter what

Comment: since you have certain indexes that mean different things (games vs buttons), you could do `const games = [...(results[0] ?? []), ...(results[1] ?? [])];`

Comment: > by "nothing", what do you mean? An empty array []? undefined? null? I'm not sure I understand because they will all execute no matter what -> sorry for not including that, it returns undefined

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*execute the other results*". Those results don't appear to be functions, so how can you execute them?

Comment: Btw, when you declare your method as `async`, you really should use `const results = await Promise.all(…);` instead of `.then()`.

Comment: made the change, and by execute I mean it gets sent to the Discord api as an array at the end

Comment: Are you saying that the result *is* `undefined` or that it *contains* `undefined` values? If the result was just an empty array, the code would already work it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore `undefined` or `null` values in the result you can just provide a default (ie empty) array before deconstruction

```
 (results) => {
   const games = [...(results[0] || []), ...(results[1] || [])];
   const buttons = [...(results[2] || []), ...(results[3] || [])];
```

or (if you have more than just a few arrays in the result and want to provide an `[]` for all of them)

```
 (results) => {
   results = results.map(x => x || []);
   const games = [...results[0]), ...results[1]];
   const buttons = [...results[2], ...results[3]];
```

But actually, the cleaner approach would be, if your methods would return an empty array instead of `undefined`

Furthermore, the way you currently defined your function, ie

```
async function foobar() {
  Promise.all([...]).then(...);
}
```

anyone calling your function `foobar` like

```
...
await foobar();
...
```

will continue *way before* your `Promise.all()` resolved.

Either do

```
function foobar() {
   return Promise.all(...).then(...);
}
```

or

```
async function foobar() {
   let result = await Promise.all(...);
   //process your result array 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for

```
async sendFreeGames(channels) {
    const [epicGames, steamGames, epicButtons, steamButtons] = await Promise.all([
        this.createEpicFreeGamesEmbeds(),
        this.createSteamFreeGamesEmbeds(),
        this.createEpicFreeButtons(),
        this.createSteamFreeButtons(),
    ]);

    const games = [...epicGames ?? [], ...steamGames ?? []].filter(Boolean);
    const buttons = [...epicButtons, ...steamButtons];

    if (games.length === 0) return;

    for (const channel of channels) {
        // @ts-ignore
        const discordAxios = axios.create({
            baseURL: 'https://discord.com/api/v10',
            headers: { Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN}` },
        });
        discordAxios.post(`/channels/${channel.data.id}/messages`, {
            embeds: games,
            components: [{ type: 1, components: buttons }],
        });
    }
}
```

Depending on what exactly those functions return, you may not need the `?? []`, or you may not need the `.filter(Boolean)`. You may also need to process your `buttons` in the same manner.